# How to convert to unique variables a list of strings with commas?

Tags: php

Lets say we have a whole string like:

```
italian, english, french, russian
```

How can we set each of those words in a unique variable? The output I am looking for is:

```
$a = "italian";
$b = "english";
$c = "french";
$d = "russian";
```

And do so for any that maybe there since they are dynamic?

We should also take the fact that white spaces may not be there as users are typing so could be:

```
italian,english, french,russian
```

Comment: you code shows javascript, yet you tagged it as php

Comment: @nogad you are correct, not a php guy here, i'm a js boy so made the mistake. Updated it now

Comment: why did you want to do that ? if you do that dynamicly you don't know the variable name who contain what

Comment: @AlainIb because I want to be able to use the variables for stats i would be calculating later on

Comment: use associative array like `['italian' => {} , 'english' =>  {}, 'french' =>  {},'russian' =>  {} ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$in="italian, english, french, russian";

$out = array_map('trim', explode(',', $in));
 //first runs the explode to split on the comma, then runs trim on each array value, to remove the extra white space
print_r($out);

Array
(
    [0] => italian
    [1] => english
    [2] => french
    [3] => russian
)
```

Comment: could you elaborate it more, not a php guy here

Comment: so to finalise your answer may I ask you how do you access french in real world for example?

Comment: `echo $out[2];` == "french"

Comment: add that comment answer for future users coming on here pls

Answer (score 0):

The following program splits the input string containing n-Comma Separate values and saves them into the variables $0 up to $(n-1) after trimming leading and trailing whitespaces

```
 <?php
        //Your input string
        $input = "text1, test2, 42, Erdbeerkäse";

        //split on ','
        $split = explode(",",$input);

        $i = 0;

        //itterate over the array of strings
        foreach( $split as $val){
            //save into $$i after trimming
            $$i = trim($val);d
            $i++;
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: fixed it, there was 'insert code here' inserted on accident

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help

```
$str = 'italian, english, french, russian';
    $level = 'easy, very easy, hard, very hard';
    $arr = explode(', ',$str);
    $level_arr = explode(', ',$level);
    $new_vars = [];
    foreach ($arr as $val){
        $$val ='';
        foreach ($level_arr as $values){
            $$val = $values;
        }

    }
    // notice the IDE will alert that the variable is not define - ignore it.
    echo $italian ;
```

Comment: oh hang on this is brilliant. Maybe adding a trim would avoid the white spaces?

Comment: if brilliant = returns "what ever you like", then sure

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: @RoyBarOn actually when I output echo $italian; it does gives me "what ever you like" why?!

Comment: The variables are now set - so you only need to set the values - $italian = 'what ever you like'....

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: ok man, i thought it was generating dynamically the variables, how can I manually set them if they are dynamic..

Comment: It does generate the variables dynamically . You can either set their values manually or set them dynamically by another array.

Comment: ok then can we show how these dynamically generated variables can get their values? or the answer will be uncomplete and what @nogad did is better actually

Comment: Updated - if it's not what you wish to accomplish - please explain your purpose

Comment: he is just splitting a coma delineated string in to septate variables, no idea how you came up with this answer.